# PrestaShop set carrier price in function getPackageShippingCost of custom module without overriding

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm developing a module that modifies carrier's price when client is in order page, (step 2 of order). Previously, I created some carriers associated with  the module, so when I arrive at the order page as a customer, prestashop calls my method `getPackageShippingCost` on my module code:

```
public function getPackageShippingCost($id_carrier = null, $use_tax = true, $default_country = null, $product_list = null, $id_zone = null)
```

I see that `$id_carrier` var received in module is not `$id_carrier` really, I see that is actual Cart Object instead, so I need a list of carriers shown in that cart in order page.

Currently, I'm trying to get that list of carriers with line:

```
$carriers = Carrier::getCarriers($cookie->id_lang, true, false, false, NULL, PS_CARRIERS_AND_CARRIER_MODULES_NEED_RANGE);
```

But `getPackageShippingCost` is called by PrestaShop several times, `$carriers` var I get is always the same, and I always need to return a price out to the function if not, price is returned as free. The problem is that I can't detect iteration of a specified carrier.

The problem is solved modifying or overriding classes/Cart.php but I don't want to use overriding, I think it is possible to do it only with the method `getPackageShippingCost` in the module.

Comment: Resuming that, what i need is available carriers list by id_cart

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i modify overriding. Is the worst-best solution.

```
class Cart extends CartCore
```

{

```
public function getPackageShippingCost($id_carrier = null, $use_tax = true, Country $default_country = null, $product_list = null, $id_zone = null)
{
    global $array_precios;
    if ($array_precios == null)
        $array_precios = Tools::jsonDecode(Module::getInstanceByName('mymodule')->buscarPreciosmymodule(Context::getContext()->cart->id, false), true);
    if (!Module::getInstanceByName('mymodule')->isMyModuleCarrier($id_carrier)) {
        return parent::getPackageShippingCost($id_carrier, $use_tax, $default_country, $product_list, $id_zone);
    }
    $objCarrier = new Carrier($id_carrier);
    if (array_key_exists($objCarrier->url, $array_precios))
    {            
        return($array_precios[$objCarrier->url]['importe']);
    }
}
```

}